# How to get more samples from ADC converter using SPI

Tags: spi, performance, c#

I am trying to use ADC converter in my raspberry which has speed around 100k smp/s. I am setting clock as producent of converter recomend for 20 Mhz. But I only recive around ~ 43k samples/s and I can't get more even if I change Clck value. I am using hardware SPI0. My question is what is default speed of SPI in raspeberry? How can I speed it up? I don't know python so I would like to avoid libaries in python to set SPI speed. I am using c# to programing my raspberry. Maybe there are some consol commands to set it ?  Thanks for you answers.

Comment: https://lmgtfy.app/?q=raspberry+pi+set+spi+speed

Answer (score 1):

The speed is probably limited by the number of transactions the Linux SPI driver can manage in one second.

See [How fast is SPI](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/faq.html#How_fast_is_SPI) for some benchmarks I did.

I suggest you try a library which bypasses the Linux SPI driver.

I am aware of two.

(My) [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html).

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#spiOpen

The [bcm2835](https://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/) library.

https://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/group__spi.html